# I am working on a Vuejs Chat app, on clicking the input message box, how do i sent the whole input div up along as keyboard shows up in android

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chat

I am working on a chat app in vuejs, this is a webview to be opened in Android. I have `input-bx` as below to send message, how do I drag the `input-bx` up so that it does get hidden when android keyboard comes up.

```
<div class="enter_msg child2" style="flex:1;  bottom: 0;" >
      <input class="input-bx msgara" placeholder="Tap here to start typing..." v-model="groupMsg" />
      <v-btn id="grpmsg" class="send_btn" :disabled="isDisable(groupMsg)" @click="sendGroupMsg()"> <p style="margin:0">Send</p></v-btn>
    </div>




.enter_msg{
  display: flex;
  flex: 3;
  position: fixed;
  width: 72%;
  padding: 2% 4%;
}


.input-bx {
  border: 1px solid #111;
}


.msgara{
background-color: #260b1c;
border: 1px solid #b92876;
border-radius: 2px;
width: 80%;
padding: 2%;
height: 38px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dragging the input up"?

Comment: When you click on the input box, the keyboard covers the android screen and my input box gets hidden below the keyboard, so input box has to be pushed up with keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposal is to temporarily bring the input to the very top of the screen while it has focus. 
This can be done by adding a flag through which we can bind a dynamic class.
The html:

```
<div class="enter_msg child2" style="flex:1;  bottom: 0;" >
  <input class="input-bx msgara" v-bind:class="{ inputBoxUp: flag }" placeholder="Tap here to start typing..." v-model="groupMsg" @focus="flag=true" @blur="flag=false"/>
  <v-btn id="grpmsg" class="send_btn"  :disabled="isDisable(groupMsg)" @click="sendGroupMsg()" > <p style="margin:0">Send</p></v-btn>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.inputBoxUp { position: fixed; top: 5px; }
```

Also just add flag in the data of the component obviously.

**Example**

Here is a codepen with the working example https://codepen.io/drewct/pen/qBdwmeM

Comment: This works, but the issue with this is only input box comes up, how do I add the send button to also go up with the input box.

Comment: I updated the codepen with what you're asking, however this is not what the question was asking for specifically. Anyways, the trick is to simply have the parent div to go up with the class binding